# My iPhone suddenly started showing me an activation error

Tags: iphone, activation-lock

I am new here so please forgive me if it's the wrong place to ask.

My iPhone suddenly showed me an Activation Error with the message "Activation could not be completed. Please restore the phone and install the latest version of IOS and attempt activation again. If the problem persists, please contact customer support." - when I googled it, some solutions would say I need to download the OS from a laptop. But I do not have a laptop, this iPhone and another phone are all I have. Please tell me what to do, I need to access my iPhone urgently. Thank you

Comment: First step is to follow the directives - contact customer support and restore the phone (same as a reset).  If you've been backing up to iCloud (which you should be doing since you say you don't have a computer), then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you sir. I've contacted customer support, they did not reply. I did not backup anything to iCloud. How do I reset it the phone? I cannot enter into anything. It just shows me a "connect to Wi-Fi" screen and when I connect, it sends me again to the activation error page.

Comment: Sir, I am still searching the internet for a solution and yet cannot find one. Could you please give me some advice? I really need to access my phone. Thanks

Comment: See the answer from @bmike below.  Part of the problem that you're running into is that you don't have the tools.  It's like having a problem with your car that won't start  - no matter how much googling you do, if you don't have the proper tools to effect a repair, there's not much you can do other than take it in for service.

Comment: If you or anybody else still struggling with this, perhaps this video can give some context of why this is happening: https://youtu.be/UxaCUugPoRY

Answer (score 1):

While you are in queue for support, why no step through this?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201407

Especially the get more support section once you have implemented each of the steps above. Usually it’s less than 30 minutes to solve most of the errors in my experience. Worst case without a computer you will need help from someone else or to ship it to service.